# php execute neverending binary/script print output live

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm running into a problem where the php script never terminates due to its work, so it never gets a chance to pass data back to ajax to display back to the user in html format.

To be more clear, what I'm trying to do is have a user click on a button on an html page, the button executes a javascript function which uses ajax to execute the php script. The php script executes a never ending command (ie: ping localhost) using popen and then I echo the output from popen. The problem is that because the php script never finishes, the echos are never reported back unless I kill the ping process, which causes the php script to end and the data echoed returned back to the javascript function to display in html.

I want to be able to see the live output when the php script is running. If I click on that button in the html website, I want the button to call the javascript function, then execute the php script and I want to see immediately every echo from the php script as it is running live. Is that possible?

Here is my code so far:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function execfunc() {
            // Clear any previous output.
            clearOutput();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "phpscript.php",
                data: "",
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#divOutput').html(msg);
                }
            }); // Ajax Call
        }

        function stopReadout() {
            // to do
        }

        function clearOutput() {
            $("#divOutput").html("");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Executing Linux Command</h3>
    <p>Push the button to execute the command "ping localhost":</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="execfunc();">Execute</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="stopReadout();">Stop</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearOutput();">Clear</button>
    <br/>
    <p id="label">Terminal output:</p>
    <br/>
    <div id="divOutput" style="width:800px;height:512px;border:1px solid black;overflow:scroll"></div>
</body>
```

phpscript.php

```
<?php
    while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any
    $cmd = 'ping localhost';
    $proc = popen($cmd, 'r');

    echo '<pre>';
    while (!feof($proc))
    {
        echo fread($proc, 4096);
        flush();
    }
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

If you run the phpscript.php by itself, it works fine and echos back to the browser window.
But if I execute the script from the index.html javascript using ajax, I don't get any live output back because the php script never finishes.

I even tried having phpscript.ph make a fifo pipe and dump the ping output into the fifo pipe, then I had another php script that echoed back 'cat fifofile', but the same behavior happens.

Any suggestions or help would truly be appreciated it!
D

Comment: ajax must to get all responseText before processing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use web sockets for that.

Comment: How would I implement web sockets to achieve my goal? Would you happen to know of an example or tutorial that you can post or provide a link? Thanks.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I learned how to use web sockets using java script and php to communicate. Thanks!